# Let flowlayoutpanel scroll with page in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, scroll

I have 2 `flowLayOutpanels` on my form. In one of the two are so many controlls added that the user must scroll down to see all controls.

I want my second `flowlayOutPanel` to always be visible. So this panel must scroll down along with the page. Is there a function to do this or do this easily? In which direction should I look to get this solved?